# A problem with WindowBuilder and SWT in java

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder, swt-awt

I've a little problem with this. IDK how to proceed or correct the error. Basically, I wanted to install WindowBuilder and SWT for some work but this error appears in all files. I just don't know how to do it. Please help!
[Here the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx6n2.png)

The error that keeps recurring is as follows:

```
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 103 (Unknown GUI toolkit). Es_1
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1199)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:244)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:160)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:150)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:553)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:468)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4803)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:470)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:484)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:432)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:389)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:90)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:275)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:252)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:127)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
```

Basically I expect it to show me a window with what I want but there is like a repetition of the error in the window shown above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update WindowBuilder from the Eclipse Marketplace after installing it. lmao